# SmartCard/NFC RDP Win7>2016 redirection doesn't work in UWP apps, but works in others

Tags: c#, uwp, smartcard, mifare, smartcard-reader

I'm RDP'ing from a client to a server 2016 server where an uwp app is installed which reads a Mifare 1K SmartCard.

The following method is used by the UWP samples provided my Microsoft. It returns the connected devices, in UWP when connected from a Windows 7 client to a server 2016 RDP host, the smartcard reader is not in the list. However, the same code works fine if I RDP from a windows 10 client to the server 2016.

```
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(query);
```

Returns the following when connected from win10 but not when connected from win7

```
  "Id:\\\\?\\SWD#ScDeviceEnum#2_Cherry_Smartcard_Terminal_TC_12xx-CL_0#{deebe6ad-9e01-47e2-a3b2-a66aa2c036c9} is \nCherry Smartcard Terminal TC 12xx-CL 0 and \nIsEnabled:True",
```

The smartcard can however be read when connecting from windows 7 to the server 2010 using the Cherry diagnostic utility provided by my smartcard reader manufacturer.

Perhaps the diagnostic utility uses one of the following devices, for which I can't seem to find an UWP NFC implementation:

```
 "Id:\\\\?\\USB#VID_046A&PID_0091&REV_0520#3&2dcee32&0&ec6dd943-cbc1-490a-baff-b383c9b837bc#        {50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}\\Slot0 is \nSmart Card Reader USB and \nIsEnabled:False",
 "Id:\\\\?\\USB#VID_046A&PID_0091&REV_0520#3&2dcee32&0&ec6dd943-cbc1-490a-baff-b383c9b837bc#        {a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} is \nSmart Card Reader USB and \nIsEnabled:False",
 "Id:\\\\?\\USB#VID_046A&PID_0091&REV_0520#3&2dcee32&0&ec6dd943-cbc1-490a-baff-b383c9b837bc#        {ca52e22c-b28a-4e5c-8521-57af65242396} is \nSmart Card Reader USB and \nIsEnabled:False",
 "Id:\\\\?\\{892EDE5E-BE49-443c-A0B3-005D74F2D69C}#ScFilter#4&352c434&0&01#             {d86354cc-a2ac-4223-95b9-2e48ce154434} is \nSmart Card Reader USB and \nIsEnabled:False",
```

So to summarize

- Win7 -> Server 2016 UWP app: BROKEN
- Win 10 -> Server 2016 UWP app: WORKS
- Win7 -> Server 2016 Cherry utility: WORKS
- Win 10 -> Server 2016 Cherry utility: WORKS

Can anyone point me towards a solution for UWP, or an idea about what's happening here?